# Show all primes in go

Tags: performance, primes, formatting, go

I'm trying to go through Adrian simple programming tasks; Elementary [task 8](https://adriann.github.io/programming_problems.html)     It's basically asking for an infinite loop to print every prime number as it finds it.

Are there too many `if` statements? Call it intuitive knowledge, but something is just bugging me, like I'm missing something. Like, I can remove one of the `if` statements. So I'm wondering what you guys will find.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var current_prime int
    var prime bool
    current_prime = 0

    for {
        prime = true
        current_prime++

        for i := 2; i < current_prime; i++ {
            if current_prime % i == 0 {
                prime = false
                i = current_prime
            }
        }

        if prime {
            fmt.Println("found prime:", current_prime);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Simple Programming Problems](https://adriann.github.io/programming_problems.html)
>
> Write a program that prints all prime numbers. (Note: if your
>   programming language does not support arbitrary size numbers, printing
>   all primes up to the largest number you can easily represent is fine
>   too.)

---

Your program says one is prime. That is not correct.

The only even prime number is two. You don't appear take advantage of that. That is inefficient.

A number can only be divisible by a number less than or equal to its square root. You don't appear take advantage of that. That is inefficient.

You are asked to "[print] all primes up to the largest number you can easily represent." In Go, type int is either 32 or 64 bits. You don't guarantee the largest number by using type int64. Your program is not correct.

You have no program termination condition. Your program is not correct.

And so on.

---

For example, fixing your code,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("prime numbers:")
    fmt.Println(2)

    for n := int64(3); n > 0; n += 2 {
        prime := true

        r := int64(math.Sqrt(float64(n))) + 1
        for i := int64(3); i < r; i += 2 {
            if n%i == 0 {
                prime = false
                break
            }
        }

        if prime {
            fmt.Println(n)
        }
    }
}
```

---

To provide a measure of performance, the results from a Go benchmark for all prime numbers up to 32,771:

```
BenchmarkPeterSO-4           500       2661556 ns/op
BenchmarkIbnRushd-4            3     492864429 ns/op
```

Comment: Minor possible performance improvement. math.Sqrt is very slow - but we know the previous sqrt

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to get a performance increase with a *faster* solution let's review your program and try to make it a *solid* one.

#### The variables

```
var current_prime int
var prime bool
current_prime = 0
```

Check this example:

```
var a int = 0 // 0
var b int     // default int value is 0, similar to above
var c = 0     // type is int, similar to above
d := 0        // same
```

The latter is short and nice, I suggest you to stick to it. `var` notation is required in package block (globals), when explicit type is needed and to overcome variable shading.

You've declared the prime variable, but is first used only within the outer loop, so declare it there. Try to introduce new variables first time you need them.

#### The outer loop

```
for {
    // ...
}
```

Your for loop is infinite since there is no loop condition or a break statement. The current_prime will [overflow](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_overflow) and you'll start printing the same/wrong numbers.

As pointed by peterSO, the first prime number is 2, so we can start with it.

```
for current_prime := 2; i > 0; i++ {
    // ...
}
```

When overflow occurs the loop condition will be falsy and the loop will terminate.

To take it further it is better not to expect `int` overflow and use MaxInt* constants from [math package](https://golang.org/pkg/math/). Apart from guaranteed proper `uint` overflow there is nothing solid about `int`, so it is better not to abuse its behavior.

#### The inner loop

```
for i := 2; i < current_prime; i++ {
    if current_prime % i == 0 {
        prime = false
        i = current_prime
    }
}
```

It took me a while to understand the purpose of `i = current_prime` line. No. This is not nice, use `break` to end the loop.

This one is *much cleaner* to me:

```
for i := 2; i < current_prime; i++ {
    if current_prime % i == 0 {
        prime = false
        break
    }
}
```

Let's take it further. After the inner loop you test the prime variable and print the current_prime number. So when you get `current_prime % i == 0` as true you already know current_prime is not a prime number and you need to continue *the outer* loop. For such purpose Golang has labels that perfectly solve the task:

```
outer:
    for prime := 2; prime > 0; prime++ {
        for i := 2; i < prime; i++ {
            if prime % i == 0 {
                continue outer
            }
        }
        fmt.Println(prime)
    }
```

A `continue outer` statement will break the inner loop and continue the outer one.
When you place a label one line before the loop you may break and continue right to it. It helps escaping nested loops a lot.

Finally lets choose the appropriate types for our task. Since we don't need the signed numbers we can use `uint` instead of `int`. Better, lets use `uint64` directly to guaranty the maximum available type. The nice thing about unsigned numbers is that Golang guarantees that they will overflow properly so we can check for zero value to terminate the loop.

#### Example rewrite

Here follows a possible rewrite of your original program:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

outer:
    for prime := uint64(2); prime > 0; prime++ {
        for i := uint64(2); i < prime; i++ {
            if prime % i == 0 {
                continue outer
            }
        }
        fmt.Println(prime)
    }
}
```

Things accomplished:

- proper types are used
- overflow is handled
- no hacks

Comment: It will be helpfull if you'll provide comments explaining your downvotes.